# MacOS Terminal find and regex issue

Tags: regex, macos, replace, find, xargs

I've spent a considerable amount of time in the last 24 hours trying to get this script to work. I've come across several threads on here that point to regex commands simply not working on a Mac in Terminal.

```
find . -name '*.yml' -print0 | xargs -0 sed -i '' -e 's/^uuid.*\n/g'
```

This script *should* go through all of the yml files in the current directory, and remove the line that starts with `uuid`.

It simply doesn't work.

I can get this to work:

```
find . -name '*.yml' -print0 | xargs -0 sed -i '' -e 's/^uuid://g
```

But it just removes the `uuid` part from the line, when I need the entire line gone and the whitespace.

I've tested my regex [here](https://regex101.com/r/C2wCDw/2) and [here](https://www.regextester.com/?fam=100005) and I believe it works correctly.

Can anyone point me in the direction of some documentation for macOS and regex?

Comment: In the first example, your `sed` command is incomplete. It's missing a slash.

Comment: also, I believe the `\n` can be removed

Comment: As GolfWolf points out, its not really a regex issue but a `sed` issue. Whith regexes its good to test with the exact tool you are currently using.

Comment: tripleee's answer worked and I'm accepting as the correct answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `s` command of `sed` requres two arguments. You can replace the entire line with an empty line by using a regex which matches the entire line (notice the `.*` regex wildcard at the end);

```
s/^uuid:.*//
```

or use the `d` command to delete any matching lines;

```
/^uuid:/d
```

The former will leave the final newline (though some `sed` dialects will let you match and substitute that, too) while deleting a line always also deletes its trailing newline.

In spite of superficial similarities, these are syntactically different. The `s` command is unconditionally applied to every line (though if the regular expression doesn't match, it doesn't substitute anything) while the `d` command has an *address expression* which only selects certain lines (again, using a regular expression, which however doesn't have to match the entire line).

Comment: The `sed` manual explains the syntax of the language, although of course it isn't a good introductory text. Any introduction to `sed` will explain these concepts in more detail; I hesitate to recommend any particular one, though I remember liking the O'Reilly `sed & awk` book many years ago (even when I already was somewhat familiar with both at the time).

Comment: Yep. That was it. According to several people I talked to, they were under impression that s/ was a delimiter for regex in terminal.